# CakePHP Helper Auto-Completion in Netbeans 6.8

Tags: cakephp, netbeans, autocomplete

Can anyone please tell me how I can "enable" CakePHP's Helper auto-completion in CakePHP? Essentially so when, for instance, I type `$form->` it gives me a list of `$form`'s methods and variables.

I have read http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/model-based-code-insight-and-completion-in-netbeans and also tried to implement comment #3. When I try that it still fails to auto complete in either a Controller or View.

Do any Netbeans & CakePHP users out there have any tips, tricks, or hacks that can get this working? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enable almost full support for CakePHP in NetBeans 6.8 just try this http://www.tiplite.com/cakephp-support-in-netbeans/

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans 6.8 there is a confirmed bug that makes the "comment #3"-method not working.
http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=180239

It seems to be resolved in version 6.9. Haven't confirmed it myself, though.