# How to configure cakephp 1.3 for netbeans 7.0?

Tags: cakephp, netbeans, cakephp-1.3

How do I configure the environment variables for cakephp 1.3?

I am trying to use netbeans 7.0 to run cakephp framework. Are there any step by step guide to setup cakephp on netbeans? I am unable to find a good source online.

Please assist. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple search for "cakephp netbeans" reveals hundres of sources. I am not sure how you could miss those:
http://www.tiplite.com/cakephp-support-in-netbeans/

it has already been asked before, by the way:
[CakePHP Helper Auto-Completion in Netbeans 6.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255503/cakephp-helper-auto-completion-in-netbeans-6-8)

in earlier versions it is the same as in 7.0. it doesnt change much.